# How to have centered content with a left menu using css only?

Tags: html, css

I have two divs:

```
<div id="left_menu" >&nbsp;menu&nbsp;</div>
<div id="content" >&nbsp;centered&nbsp;</div>
```

Currently they have a css of

```
#content {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:table;
}
```

So this would create a div with menu and a line below that a centered div with centered.  What I want is a centered div#content with div#left_menu to the left of it.  I DON'T want to center BOTH the divs together, only the div#content.  This should be done with only divs and css and should work on all browsers.

So this could possibly look like

---> menu  centered <--------

Just to clarify things:

I'm not centering/positioning the text, it's the divs that matter (text is there for marking the position in the example).  I want both divs on the same line (like a span, but i want to use divs), the centered div should be centered in the middle of the page. The menu div should be right next to it, touching the left border of the centered div.

This solution should work for every screen size (e.g. if the screen is very large the two side gaps to the left and right of the menu and content should be very large, e.g. if the screen is too small for both the menu and content, there should be no gaps and the result should look like (the >< represent the cutoff) Notice how if the screen is too small, the menu div is fully displayed first with the centered div cutoff (as if it were just two divs floated left).

```
>menu  cent<
```

Due to the number of incorrect answers being submitted:

1) Please verify your answers by creating your own .html file with your code

2) Refresh once on full screen and refresh once with browser resized to a smaller size such that the browser cannot hold both divs (e.g. the centered div is semi-cutoff)

3) Use inspect element tool(chrome) or equivalent tools to be sure that the two divs are touching, the centered div is indeed centered, etc

To further clarify what i want i've included a better example(NOT a solution though):

This does not work for every screen size:
http://jsfiddle.net/prt38/2/

Answer (score 2):

**Updated per requests in comments.**

I really like using the `vertical-align` property when vertically-aligning elements.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <span id="alignment"></span><div id="wrapper">
        <div id="sidebar">

        </div><div id="main">

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

*Notice how the closing  and the succeeding  are touching. For inline and inline-block elements to touch, there cannot be space between them in the markup.*

CSS:

```
html, body { 
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center; }
#container { white-space: nowrap; }
#wrapper { 
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-align: left;
    margin: 0 75px 0 0;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
#alignment { 
    height: 100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
#sidebar {
    background: red;
    width: 75px;
    height: 200px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
#main { 
    background: blue;
    width: 300px;
    height: 400px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    display: inline-block; }
```

Preview: http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/2Xrcm/8/

Comment: both the sidebar and content are centered. notice in my example, http://jsfiddle.net/prt38/2/, that only the content is centered while the sidebar is attached to the left of it.

Comment: Just add a negative margin the width of the sidebar on the sidebar. For the 75px sidebar I have in my demo, I added `margin: 0 0 0 -75px` to `#sidebar`. See http://jsfiddle.net/Wexcode/2Xrcm/1/

Comment: notice how as you decrease the size(width) of the result box, the red div is the first to disappear, which is not what is desired.  The blue div is be first cutoff from the right side with the red div's left border touching the left border of the result div.

Comment: the desired effect when the browser's (in this case the result div) width decreasing should be like http://jsfiddle.net/2Xrcm/6/

Comment: that effect is what i mean by "this solution should work for every screen size"

Comment: By definition of something being centered, it must have equal space on either side of it. I updated the post to what I believe is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Your do it with simple `overflow:hidden` like this:

```
#left_menu{
    float:left;
    width:200px;
    height:100px;
    background:green;
}
#content {
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    display:table;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

### http://jsfiddle.net/hnXqg/

Comment: this doesn't work on my pc, possibly because of the different screen size?, there is a gap between the green and red divs.  the left menu should be touching the left border of the centered div

Comment: all i get is a centered red div with a green div floated all the way on the left of  the page on the same line, which isn't what i'm looking for. Both divs should be next to each other, the red div centered, and both on the same line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div align="center">
<span id="left_menu">&nbsp;menu&nbsp;</span>
<span id="content">&nbsp;centered&nbsp;</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to use span, but either way even with span, this is incorrect because I don't want to center the both the menu and the content, only the content.

Answer (score 0):

The solution for this is you have to create a wrapper class or id for a div like..

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="left_menu" >&nbsp;menu&nbsp;</div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="content" >&nbsp;centered&nbsp;</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then the css is..

```
#wrapper{
    margin:0px auto;
    display:table;
    width:90%;
}

#menu{
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    margin:5px;
}

#right{
   float:right;
   display:block;
}

#content{
    displat:table;
    margin:0px auto;
}
```

Comment: this does not center the content div for every screen size.

Comment: also on my pc, the divs aren't even on the same line, the menu div is on top 90% width, display:block, while the centered div isn't even centered, on the line below the menu div, floated all the way to the right.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for. Adjust the sizes to suit your needs, obviously.

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        margin: auto;
        width: 500px;
    }

    .menu {
        margin: 10px;
        width: 180px;
    }

    .content {
        margin: 10px;
        width: 280px;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .floatLeft {
        float: left;
    }

    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="menu floatLeft">
        Menu
    </div>

    <div class="content floatLeft">
        Content
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Edited:

```
<style type="text/css">
    .container {
        margin: auto;
        width: 500px;;
        background: red;
    }

    .menu {
        width: 50px;
        margin-left: 50px;
        background: green;
    }

    .content {
        width: 300px;
        margin: auto;
        background: blue;
    }

    .floatLeft {
        float: left;
    }

    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }
</style>

<div class="container">
    <div class="menu floatLeft">
        Menu
    </div>

    <div class="content">
        Content
    </div>

    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: both the menu and content here is center. the content should be the only one center with the menu div touching the left border of the content

Comment: The wording of your question isn't very clear so it's hard to interpret. I'll update my answer.

Comment: the use of the container forces the menu div to always be 50px to the left of the beginning of the container, meaning if the browser width < container width, the menu div would not align to the left of the browser, therefore, this solution would not work for all browser sizes.

Answer (score 0):

I think this css should do the job, if I understood your question:

```
#left_menu{background:red;
width:100px;
height:100px;
float:left;
margin: auto 0;
z-index:2}
#content {
  background:white;
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
margin: auto 0;
float:left;
position:absolute;
left:20%;
z-index:200;
padding-left:4%
}
```

And  Html is below:

```
<div id="left_menu" >RED DIV</div>
<div id="content" >WHITE DIV</div>
```

Comment: the white div isn't centered for every screen size and also the red div isn't touching the left of the red div, it's just floated left

Answer (score -1):

html { text-align: center; }
div#content { display: inline; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left;width: 980px; }

something like this should work.

Comment: it doesn't. i'm aligning the divs not the text, the text is just there as a marker for the divs

Comment: You actually tried to put this and add something else? And why these -1 on everyone? We are trying to help not trouble you, there is no need for -1.

Comment: Yes, I've tried every answer and every edit here. The reason why I -1 is because I have edited three times my question to further clarify what I want and all people do is answer the question assuming they are right even though 1) they don't even try their own answers to see if it matches my example 2) some answers are so wrong/off it seems like they didn't read the question or have no idea what they are talking about.

Comment: Normally I wouldn't mind this, but the trend on this site is that the more answers for a question there are, the less likely another person bothers answering, so I'd prefer people who actually put some thought into their answers.